# Detach application from gitlab runner

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application using gitlab ci.
It's actually deployed succesful, but the gitlab build never ends, it remains always in "Running" state.

My gitlab-ci.yml job is:

`run-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-D$SPRING_BOOT_PROFILE"'
  environment: test
  allow_failure: false`

I tried with nohup, but same result, keeps "running".

`- 'nohup mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-D$SPRING_BOOT_PROFILE" &'`

Any idea?

Comment: Well you are trying to deploy your application, I think (just a guess) that is keeps "running" because you told it to: `spring-boot:run` This actually run your application according: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html See section 19.3

Comment: Right, that's because I tried nohup, but same result.

Comment: Have you tried to take out the `spring-boot:run` parameter?

Comment: Which goal would replace spring-boot:run? I'd like to deploy

Comment: `mvn deploy ........`